# Cannot save content with an empty name on content save at controller level in Umbraco 8

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco8

I am getting this error on saving and Publish `"Cannot save content with an empty name"` at controller level in Umbraco 8
I have a simple method in surface controller after form submit, which has a file upload and name and email, but after save and publish, I get this error that `"Cannot save content with an empty name"`

```
IContentService contentService = Services.ContentService;
var content = contentService.CreateContent("samplename", udi, sample.ModelTypeAlias);
content.SetValue("entry", model.FileUpload);

 contentService.SaveAndPublish(content);
```

Before this it worked fine in umbraco 7 for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So for anyone facing the same issue, the answer i found was to set the culture if u have multi cultures enabled for your site

```
contentService.SaveAndPublish(content, "en-US");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you give the node a name? I'm thinking that all Umbraco content (at least as a rule of thumb) needs a unique URL, which cannot be created if the node has no name. Might be a new sanity check for v8, but a good one as far as I see it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jannik, i have edited my post to include creation code, could you maybe point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, it looks pretty okay to me. Will it save if you don't set any values? Is the parent UDI valid? Are you allowed to create content of "sample.ModelTypeAlias" under the node you are trying to?

Comment: Yes, the udi is correct and also the content is allowed under the node, i am able to save using same details from backoffice as well, not sure what i am missing here

Answer (score 0):

[CreateContent()](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v8/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Services.IContentService.html#Umbraco_Core_Services_IContentService_Create_System_String_System_Guid_System_String_System_Int32_) only sets the Node name, but not the culture specific name of the content.

You will need to use [SetCultureName()](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v8/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Models.IContentBase.html#Umbraco_Core_Models_IContentBase_SetCultureName_System_String_System_String_). This method sets the culture sepcific name, which is the empty `name` value that the error is complaining about on the `SaveAndPublish()`

```cs
IContentService contentService = Services.ContentService;
var content = contentService.CreateContent("samplename", udi, sample.ModelTypeAlias);

// You will need to set the culture specific name
content.SetCultureName("sampleName", culture)

content.SetValue("entry", model.FileUpload);

contentService.SaveAndPublish(content);
```